# findFragmentByTag keeps returning Null in Android using ViewPager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2, fragmentstateadapter

I was trying to pass data from the Parent Activity to the `viewPager`, and I found a solution using `findFragmentByTag` but it returns Null and I'm not sure what I missed.

The [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntM6_KNPGjI) I found used a deprecated `FragmentPagerAdapter` and I think maybe that's why my implementation doesn't work, so I'm looking for a way forward.

```
(supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag) as StopwatchFragment?)?.displayData(
            min!!,
            sec!!,
            millis!!
        )
```

is null

**Main Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), StopwatchListener {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
       ...
        binding.viewPagerMain.adapter = PageAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)
       
    }
...
 override fun getTheTime(min: String?, sec: String?, millis: String?) {
        val tag =
            "android:switcher:" + R.id.view_pager_main.toString() + ":" + binding.viewPagerMain.currentItem
        Log.d("Main", tag)
        (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag) as StopwatchFragment?)?.displayData(
            min!!,
            sec!!,
            millis!!
        )
    }
}
```

**PageAdapter**

```
class PageAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {

    override fun getItemCount() = 3

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> {
                RepsFragment()
            }
            1 -> {
                StopwatchFragment()
            }
            2 -> {
                TimerFragment()
            }
            else -> {
                RepsFragment()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> val tag =
>         "android:switcher:" + R.id.view_pager_main.toString() + ":" + binding.viewPagerMain.currentItem
> ```

This is valid for the `ViewPager` not `ViewPager2`.

In order to do that for `ViewPager2`, you need:

```
val tag = "f$pageId"
```

And this requires to have unique IDs for the pages, for simplicity you can set them as the `ViewPager` positions; to do so override `getItemId()` of the adapter:

```
class PageAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {

    // ... 

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }
}
```

And then the `pageId` will be the current page (or any page position you want), and hence the tag would be:

```
val tag = "f$binding.viewPagerMain.currentItem"
```

Comment: The error changed, now it's saying specifically ```null cannot be cast to non-null type com.homeofficeprojects.countmyrepstoo.StopwatchFragment```. So the ```supportFragmentManager``` is still not finding the fragment

Comment: Is that raised on `(supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag) as StopwatchFragment?)` ?

Comment: no, the code I used removes the null checks because the data wasn't transferring and I wanted to see where the disconnect was val tag =
            "f${binding.viewPagerMain.currentItem}"
     
        val f = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag) as StopwatchFragment
    }

Comment: This could happen if you try to access the ViewPager fragment before attaching the adapter to it; or when the ViewPager is not present at the current screen

Comment: it seems that no matter where I place the call to the function, it doesn't seem to be finding the Fragment

Comment: Do you try to get fragment that still did not load?.. You can set the number of offsecreen fragments that can be loaded by viewpager.. Those fragments can also only be returned by this answer... Other fragments can't be returned because they are still not transacted by supportFragmentManager

Comment: I think I misunderstood the original purpose of this code. I was trying to get info from one activity to the Fragment in the ```viewpager``` through the parent activity of the ```viewpager``` but this code is apparently to get info from one fragment to another in the ```viewpager```, so I think that's why it still isn't working. I ended up using ```sharepreferences```, since I ran out of places to look for an answer. If you have any advice, It would be appreciated.